# How to run between and like clause while using Pagination and Sorting With Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have to execute a query which is

```
SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE account LIKE '%deepak%' and date_created BETWEEN 'Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2015' AND 'Wed Dec 16 00:00:00 IST 2015' ORDER BY date_created ASC OFFSET 5 LIMIT 10;
```

currently I am able to perform 4 functions using JPA which are:-

- Set Offset
- Set Page Size
- Set Direction
- Set Sort by column name

using the following code:-

```
PageRequest request = new PageRequest(1, 10, Sort.Direction.ASC, date_created );
return transactionRepository.findAll(request);
```

**But how to perform remaining functions i.e. 'between' clause and 'like' clause using Pagination and Sorting With Spring Data JPA**

Other suggested methods are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Spring jpa data reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/) ,

Add this to your `repository` that extends `PagingAndSortingRepository<..,..>`

```
findByAccountLikeAndDateCreatedBetween(String account,Date start,Date end,Pageable pageable)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with JPQL you can always annotate a query with `@Query` inside your repository. ie:

```
@Query("select t from transaction t where t.name like ?1")
List<Transaction> getTransactions(String name, Pageable pageable)
```

where ?1 is the first parameter you passed, in this case name. Note that Pageable must always be the last parameter. This way you can name your query whatever you want.

See more info [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query).